# Apache2 Kerberos auth not working as expected

Tags: apache-2.4

im using Apache 2.4.23 and want to use kerberos auth when accessing my Intranet. My apache config looks like (dont get irritated by the first vhost firma2020 thats a temporary vhost because we have a reverse proxy to reach a specific site from the outside so i had to add this virtual host)

```
<VirtualHost 10.160.144.165:443>
        DocumentRoot "/opt/EIRP/htdocs/intranet2019"
        ServerName firma2020.de
        ServerAlias firma2020.de
Redirect permanent /start/ https://firma2020.de/corona


<Directory "/opt/EIRP/htdocs/intranet2019">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks

                ###############SSO + LDAP CONFIG################
                AuthType Kerberos
                AuthName "Intranet Login"
                KrbAuthRealm firma.de
                KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet2019.firma.de@firma.de
                Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/apache.keytab
                KrbMethodK5Passwd on
                KrbMethodNegotiate off 

                AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server.firma.de:3268/DC=int,DC=firma,DC=de?userPrincipalName"
                AuthLDAPBindDN 'svc_intranet2019_sso@firma.de'
                AuthLDAPBindPassword '1Bqj*9y_oDv!43z'
                Require ldap-group CN=AP_UG_Intranet_Zugriff,OU=GrpAppl,OU=ZentraleRessourcen,OU=firma,DC=int,DC=
firma,DC=de

                ## User fÃ¼r Icinga Checks - IMA-0001863544 ##
                Require valid-user svc_intranet2019_sso
</Directory>

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

        #   You can use per vhost certificates if SNI is supported.
         SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/1.crt
         SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/1.key
         SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/1..de.pem

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.160.144.165:443>
        ServerName intranet2019.firma.de
        ServerAlias intranet.firma.de
        DocumentRoot /opt/EIRP/htdocs/intranet2019
        LogLevel          trace7
        LimitRequestFieldsize 65536
        LimitRequestLine 65536
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8


<Directory "/opt/EIRP/htdocs/intranet2019">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks

                ###############SSO + LDAP CONFIG################
                AuthType Kerberos
                AuthName "Intranet Login"
                KrbAuthRealm firma.de
                KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet2019.firma.de@firma.de
                Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/apache.keytab
                KrbMethodK5Passwd on
                KrbMethodNegotiate on


                AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ad1.firma.de:3268/DC=int,DC=firma,DC=de?userPrincipalName"
                AuthLDAPBindDN 'svc_intranet2019_sso@firma.de'
                AuthLDAPBindPassword 'mypassword'
                Require ldap-group CN=AP_UG_Intranet_Zugriff,OU=GrpAppl,OU=ZentraleRessourcen,OU=FIRMAXXX,DC=int,DC=firma,DC=de

                ## User fÃ¼r Icinga Checks - IMA-0001863544 ##
                Require valid-user svc_intranet2019_sso
</Directory>

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

        #   You can use per vhost certificates if SNI is supported.
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/star.firma.de.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/star.firma.de.key
</VirtualHost>
```

but when i enter my credentials i get access even if im not in the correct group

```
[Mon Dec 14 13:22:32.187412 2020] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 12639] mod_authnz_ldap.c(986): [client 10.30.2.17:57074] AH01718: auth_ldap authorise: require group (sub-group) "CN=AP_UG_Intranet_Zugriff,OU=GrpAppl,OU=ZentraleRessourcen,OU=FIRMAXXX,DC=int,DC=firma,DC=de": didn't match with attr DN failed group verification. [uniqueMember][5 - Compare False]
[Mon Dec 14 13:22:32.187417 2020] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 12639] mod_authnz_ldap.c(993): [client 10.30.2.17:57074] AH01720: auth_ldap authorize group: authorization denied for user username@domain.de to /start/
[Mon Dec 14 13:22:32.187424 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12639] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.30.2.17:57074] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=AP_UG_Intranet_Zugriff,OU=GrpAppl,OU=ZentraleRessourcen,OU=FIRMAXXX,DC=int,DC=firma,DC=de: denied
[Mon Dec 14 13:22:32.187430 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12639] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.30.2.17:57074] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user svc_intranet2019_sso: granted
[Mon Dec 14 13:22:32.187436 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12639] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.30.2.17:57074] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

I dont understand why i get acces by just entering my correct username and password. I would expect to get blocked because the ldap group isnt assigned

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.

First its not

`require valid-user svc_intranet2019_sso` you have to use `require user svc_intranet2019_sso`

also i had to set a `<Requireany> </Requireany>` it now looks like this

```
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks

                ###############SSO + LDAP CONFIG################
                AuthType Kerberos
                AuthName "Intranet Login"
                KrbAuthRealm firma.de
                KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet2019.firma.de@firma.de
                Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/apache.keytab
                KrbMethodK5Passwd on
                KrbMethodNegotiate off 

                AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server.firma.de:3268/DC=int,DC=firma,DC=de?userPrincipalName"
                AuthLDAPBindDN 'svc_intranet2019_sso@firma.de'
                AuthLDAPBindPassword '1Bqj*9y_oDv!43z'
<RequireAny>
Require ldap-group CN=AP_UG_Intranet_Zugriff,OU=GrpAppl,OU=ZentraleRessourcen,OU=firma,DC=int,DC=firma,DC=de

                ## User fÃ¼r Icinga Checks - IMA-0001863544 ##
                Require user svc_intranet2019_sso
</RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

With this its now working :)